# Why validation accuracy remains at 75% while train accuracy is 100 %?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used my own data set to train a model using retrain.py file from Tensorflow site. However, with my first set of images, I am seeing test accuracy of 100% while validation accuracy is at 70%. I see that validation entropy is increasing which tells overfitting. I am new to this field and got to this stage by following online tutorials.

I did not enable random brightness, crop and flip yet for training. I am trying to understand why is this behaviour? I tried flower example and it worked as expected. Cross-entropy got lowest instead of increasing with my data set.

Could some one explain whats going on inside the CNN here ?

[image]

Comment: How many epochs are you training? It actually look like you shoukd stop sooner as well. Even if you add regularisation you will eventually overfit if you just keep going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model has over-fitted on the training data. If its a large model, you should consider using transfer learning where you train the model on a large dataset like ImageNet and then fine-tune on your data. You can also try adding some form of regularization to prevent overfitting specially `Dropout` and `L2 regularization`.

Comment: It is transfer learning if that model was trained for some other task and you use those 'learned weights' and resume training from there.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means your model is overfitting. Overfitting means your model is not generalizing well to unseen data (ie the validation data). What you can do is add some form of regularization (L2 is used normally). What this does is it penalizes weights from getting very high values which would thereby lead to overfitting. This will also act against the model trying to fit outliers which again leads to less generalization and more overfitting.

Comment: What is L2 here ?. retrain.py uses Inception v3

Comment: L2 is a regularization method. It has nothing to do with the model. You simply add it to the loss function you are trying to minimize. All major libraries allow you to do this by simply setting some kind of regularization parameter.

Comment: where do u set that in retrain.py ?

Comment: I do not know what retrain.py is.